# I have a function setup as an onClick event that sends a set of data back to an API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, onclick, axios

I have a function in my React app setup as an onClick event that sends a set of data back to an API and then I need it to redirect to another URL AFTER it finishes sending the data. I had previously tried to do this by simply wrapping the button with an anchor tag and an href, but whenever a user hits the button it redirects before the onClick event finishes. I've included the function below. Any ideas on how to add a redirect after the initial sending logic?

Function

```
this.submitData = () => {
  let temporalDataModel = {
    ...this.state.dataModel,
    SessionId: this.state.customer.SessionId,
    customerId: this.state.customer.CustomerId
  };

  //// This is the logic to send the the data back to my API

  let postUrl = "https://myAPI.com/OfferUpdate";
  axios
    .post(postUrl, temporalDataModel)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
    });

  console.log("This is your data...sending...NOW", temporalDataModel);
};
```

Comment: So you redirect when the call comes back.... window.location.href = "//example.com"

Comment: @epascarello that was all it took, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your posting code in side then function like below, As your posting code is out of then function it is executing before api gets back with result.

```
axios
  .post(postUrl, temporalDataModel)
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
    console.log("This is your data...sending...NOW", temporalDataModel);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Well actually your submitData function execute async code... So if you want to wait until the action is done, you should redirect to the other website in the result of your promise in the `then` or `catch`if an exception occur.